# C++ project fails to build due to incompatible static library

Tags: makefile, g++, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to build a c++ project on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.
the project is 32-bit.
At the terminal output I receive such lines:

> ibcrypto.a(bio_b64.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
>
> /usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
>   gnu/libcrypto.a(bio_asn1.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[2]: ***  [linux/release_32/cesmagent] Error 1

I thought it had something to do with libssl0.9.8, but so I did "sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386" but there already was the newest version of it.

Can any one please help me here?

Comment: Does `locate libcrypto.a` say what you'd expect?

Comment: it returns the same path as in error messages

Answer (score 0):

The linker is trying to link against the 64-bit version of `libcrypto.a` because it can't find a 32-bit version.

You say you have this:

```
$ locate libcrypto.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
```

Whereas, you *need* this:

```
$ locate libcrypto.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
```

(I thought you could have both, but it turns out, on 12.04, it's impossible to have both because the packages conflict.)

You can install the i386 library like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev:i386
```

Basically, you probably had the run-time libraries installed correctly, but you did not have the developer libraries.

Comment: Thank's, that will help to build 32-bit project. But as it happens I need to have 64-bit version of libssl as well.
Unfortunately you are right about packages conflict, which is described here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=689093

Comment: I'd recommend LXC to create a 32-bit 12.04 so you can keep them separate.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround which solved my problem:

I installed 32-bit version library

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev:i386

the 64-bit library was removed by that.
in the directory /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu I found 32-bit version libcrypto.a and put it in /usr/lib32

Then I installed 64-bit library

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

in the directory /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu I found 64-bit version libcrypto.a and put it in /usr/lib64

in the Makefile of a project I adjusted paths /usr/lib32/libcrypto.a and /usr/lib64/libcrypto.a to be dependent on the corresponding command argument.

the project builds!